# how to find the root of given polynomials

Tags: calculus

suppose that there is a sequence $P_0(x),P_1(x),...,P_i(x),...  $ of polynomials where $P_i$ is a polynomial of degree $i$ with the following property :

$1) P_0(x)=1$

$2) \forall n,m \geq 0 , n \neq m ; \int_0^1 P_n(x)P_m(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}$

show that there is exactly $i$ different root for $P_i$.

---

I have tried induction and using rolle theorem and mean value show's the induction step but I have failed to prove the induction base case ([you can check here for more details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672193/show-that-there-is-a-root-in-0-1)),
then I have tried to modify polynomials to get an orthogonal set but I couldn't.

at last, I tried to find the polynomials constants using the property (2) and this led to finding the polynomials uniquely but you need to find them one by one and in order, so I can not give an actual proof for the problem.

P.S: sorry for bad English.

Comment: Are the roots supposed to be in $[0,1]$ or in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Actually you can perform normalization in terms of $I_k=\int\limits_0^1 P_k(x)P_k(x)dx$ but I don't see how it helps. I'd be glad if you updated your question with that. Thanks.

Comment: You write "$P_i$ is a polynomial of degree $i$", by the fundamental theorem there are $i$ complex roots, counted with multiplicity. So is the question to show that there are no multiple roots or is there some claim implied that all roots are real?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  the roots can be complex.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Just needs to show that the roots are not counted multiple times.